# When I try to add Strings to an Array List I get an "illegal start of type error"

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array list meant to hold employee ID numbers but when I try to add String to it gives me the titular error. I read that I can solve this by moving my additions into the constructor or a method but for the purposes of this Array List I cannot do that as I will be removing objects from it as well. What type am I illegally starting? I use Blue J. This is not the full program only the constructor and what is above it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Employee{
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  private static ArrayList<String> employeeID = new ArrayList<String>();
  employeeID.add<"632584">;
  employeeID.add<"259415">;
  employeeID.add<"257412">;
  employeeID.add<"953647">;
  employeeID.add<"126497">;
  employeeID.add<"453256">;
  employeeID.add<"125689">;

  private String employeeName; //A String to hold an employee’s full name.

  private int hours; //An integer to hold the number of hours worked by each employee.
  private double payRate; //A double to hold each employee’s hourly pay rate.
  private double wages; //A doubles to hold each employee’s gross wages. 
  private String ID; // A string to hold each employee's ID.

  /**
   * Create a new employee on the payroll with a given name, hours, pay rate, and wages.
   */
  public Employee(){

    ID = employeeID[0];

    System.out.println("What is the employee's full name?");
    employeeName = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("What is the employee's hourly pay rate?");
    payRate = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine(); //consumes next line
    System.out.println("");
  }
}
```

Comment: The syntax is `add("foo");`.

Comment: Plus: You cannot `add` something without a surrounding method/static initializer/whatever. Try a static initialization block as described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add items to a static list you can use the block static{}

```
public class Employee {
....

 private static ArrayList <String> employeeID = new ArrayList <String> ();
 static {
  employeeID.add("632584");
  employeeID.add("259415");
  employeeID.add("257412");
  employeeID.add("953647");
  employeeID.add("126497");
  employeeID.add("453256");
  employeeID.add("125689");
 }

...
 }
}
```

Or use constructor

```
public class Employee {
....

 private static ArrayList <String> employeeID = new ArrayList <String> ()
 {{
  add("632584");
  add("259415");
  add("257412");
  add("953647");
  add("126497");
  add("453256");
  add("125689");
 }};

...
 }
}
```